# Retrieve MPMediaItemArtwork from Album Id

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmediaquery

I have an albumId ( say "-7833645336740617216" ). I am looking at a method similar which can take this as an input, and return the MPMediaItemArtwork associated with this album.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to fetch the album with a `MPMediaPropertyPredicate`, and perform a `MPMediaQuery` with the predicate. Then get the value of the `MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork` property from the representative item of the album:

```c
- (MPMediaItemArtwork *)albumArtworkForAlbumID:(NSNumber *)albumID
{
    MPMediaPropertyPredicate *albumIDPredicate;
    albumIDPredicate = [MPMediaPropertyPredicate predicateWithValue:albumID
                                                        forProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumPersistentID];

    NSSet *predicateSet = [NSSet setWithObject:albumIDPredicate];
    MPMediaQuery *albumQuery;
    albumQuery = [[MPMediaQuery alloc] initWithFilterPredicates:predicateSet];

    MPMediaItemCollection *album;
    album = [albumQuery.collections firstObject];

    return [album.representativeItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork];
}
```